# Connecting to MS-SQL from pyodbc using windows authentication

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, windows-authentication, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to MSSQL server using pyodbc. I can connect to the server and query it using the basic authentication mode as:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.2.119;DATABASE=dbame;UID=**;PWD=****")
```

Connection to MSSQL can also be done using Windows Authentication where it takes the parameters

```
DOMAIN
USERNAME
PASSWORD
```

I don't know how to use this sort of credential from pyodbc to connect to the MSSQL Server.

Furthermore, the ODBC driver I am using (Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server) needs licensing. Don't we get such drivers for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Easysoft SQL Server driver parameters to use NTLM authentication are

Trusted_Domain=<domain name>

NTLMv2=Yes|No

Trusted_Connection=Yes|No

And UID, PWD as usual.

NTLM can also be triggered simply using a UID that looks like

DOMAIN\USER

If you want to use Kerberous, the following can be set

ServerSPN=SPN

Its all the the user guide for the driver

Answer (score 1):

> connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.2.119;DATABASE=dbame;UID=**;PWD=****")

The string part of the connection is what is known as a DSN-Less connection so you can pass in any of the attributes required for example :-

connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.2.119;DATABASE=dbame;UID=MyWindowsUserName;PWD=MyPassword;Trusted_Domain=MyWindowsDomainName;Trusted_Connection=1")

Trusted_Connection = 1 tells the Easysoft driver that you intend to use the Trusted_Domain, user ( UID ) and password ( PWD ) to login to SQL Server.

For a full list of all the attributes available within the **[Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/index.html)** please read the **[Attributes](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/manual/configuration.html#869916)** section of the manual.